# Looking for an XSLT community

Tags: xslt

I do a lot of XSLT programming.  I also do Java, PL/SQL, JavaScript, and a few others.  I can easily find communities of Java and JavaScript programmers via the web.  PL/SQL is a little more difficult, but between [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technology/index.html) and [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/), I do pretty well.  But XSLT seems to be neglected to me.  Where do you go for XSLT?  I know about [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp), and its great, but I'm beyond tutorials.

While SO is a great community, it is telling that the tags for this question have a combined usage of a only 188.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [xsl-list](http://www.mulberrytech.com/xsl/xsl-list/) is really active, and a lot of the big names in XSLT (such as Michael Kay) participate.

Answer (score 3):

The [**xsl-list**](http://www.mulberrytech.com/xsl/xsl-list/) is the mailing list dedicated to XSLT questions.

XSLT questions are often submitted and answered:

- in the [**Saxon mailing list**](http://mailto:saxon-help@lists.sourceforge.net)
  (for questions related to the Saxon
  XSLT (1.0 and 2.0) processors)
- in the [**xml-dev**](http://mailto:xml-dev@lists.xml.org) mailing
      list.
- in the [**comp.text.xml**](http://news:comp.text.xml)
      newsgroup
- in the microsoft newsgroups:
      [**microsoft.public.xslt**](http://news:microsoft.public.xslt),
      [**microsoft.public.xml**](http://news:microsoft.public.xml) and
      [**microsoft.public.dotnet.xml**](http://news:microsoft.public.dotnet.xml)

Hope this helped.

Cheers,

Dimitre Novatchev

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is still active, but you might find http://www.exslt.org/ interesting.

Comment: Latest news post on that site was over two years ago... 09/05/2006... but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow, of course!

[Altova](http://www.altova.com/) has some impressive looking XML tools.  I often see them listed in Google's results when I am looking for general XML help.  A quick search on their site gave a decent looking list of XSLT docs.

Comment: Yeah, yeah... SO... I knew someone would say that.  And I don't need a tool, I need a community.

Comment: Not saying that SO is just a tool, and its a great community, but it is not XSLT oriented, it anything and everything oriented.  Altova's stuff is the tool I refer to.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community, and Altova's forums appear to meet the critera of a community as well.

Comment: I guess my point is that their forum for XSLT is labeled: "Creating, debugging and executing XSLT and XQuery stylesheets with Altova products"... sounds like a tool forum, hence the "with Altova products".

Answer (score 0):

[microsoft.public.xsl](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.xsl) looks active. If newsgroups are your kind of thing.

Comment: Am I gonna get flamed there since I use Java and Oracle's XDK?

Comment: Not, if you don't mention it. ;-) No, of course not. It is about XSL, not about Microsoft.